# Querying Custom Post Type, ordering by Custom Taxonomy Pagination Not Working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination

Maybe there's a better way to do this. Let me explain what I have right now:

I have a custom post type (Products), and a custom taxonomy (Manufacturers).

What I have outputting so far:

```
Manufacturer Name 1
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3

Manufacturer Name 2
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
```

This is great, except pagination is being ignored. All 20+ products are being listed, BUT the page links are working.

My code:

```
<ul class="product-listing list-unstyled">
    <?php

    $categories = get_terms('manufacturer');

    foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
    <li class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h3><?php echo $category->name; ?></h3>
        </div>
    </li>

    <?php
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'taxonomy' => $category->taxonomy,
        'term' => $category->slug,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
    ));
        foreach($posts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 product-copy">
                <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php echo $category->name.' - '.get_the_title(); ?>
                </a></h5>
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 35 ); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I've been staring at this code for too long, and trying different solutions. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$paged` variable like this :

```
<?php

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'taxonomy' => $category->taxonomy,
        'term' => $category->slug,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bindiya. I added the paged lines to my code, but its still displaying all posts. I changed the 'posts_per_page' to 3 as well (to test), and it had no effect - still shows all. Any ideas?

Comment: Bindiya - after thinking about this, it seems turning manufacturers into its own custom post type is probably the way to go. I'll have to do some digging into this.

Comment: You have to set both `posts_per_page` and `paged`

Answer (score 0):

Pagination would not work automatically for `get_posts()` function until you added `$paged` variable.

Comment: Exactly what was proposed in the first answer. Your answer is useless as an answer with some code to support what your saying. As your answer stands, it should be added as a comment, not an answer,  -1

Comment: Oh, it's okay.. That was the first time I was answered on WPSE. That's why I actually did not know when I have to post a comment or an answer. Thanks for this concern. :)